# Which deleted question show up on the "recently deleted" tool?

Tags: support, user-interface, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

The question is as in the title : what are the criteria for deleted questions to be listed in the "recently deleted" list available to high-rep users?  My initial assumption was that it included everything, but I don't think this is the case.  Indeed, there are questions posted today that I left comments on that have clearly been deleted (they are no longer on the list of questions on the user screen of the OP), but which are not on the list of deleted questions.

Comment: That tool does not list self-deleted posts. Other than that, I can't think of much that wouldn't be listed.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais : Ah, that must be it.  Where is it documented that it does not list self-deleted posts?  And do you know the reason?

Comment: I added some specific tags and removed 'bug' in the process, as now it seems not optimal.

Comment: Related posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531) and [Which deletions are not shown in 10k-tools? Are posts deleted by roomba shown there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301539) (Of course, SEDE offers some way to view *links* to all deleted questions, but it is much less comfortable and updated only once a week. Some queries can be found here: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [description of moderator tools](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is a bit short on details. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4576) is a slightly more detailed description of these tools. The relevant part is the following:

> The delete category has views relating to questions and answers that have been or are being deleted or undeleted:
>
> - Most delete votes, sorted by number of votes
> - Most undelete votes, sorted by number of votes
> - Recently deleted (not by owner), sorted by time
> - Recently undeleted (not by owner), sorted by time

So the tool does not list self-deletions. Indeed, bringing more attention to these would go against the point of deleting one's own posts. (However, the moderators do have a separate tool to view self-deleted posts.)

Comment: Great, this answers my question completely.  Thanks!